# Optimaze comparing two dataframes with fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, fuzzywuzzy

I've two dataframe (xlsx-file).

`df_source` contains information about books that have already been loaded (66,000 rows).

`df_sort`   contains information about books that need to be sorted for loaded (36,000 rows).

I need to compare each row in `df_sort` with each in `df_source`.

The strings can be slightly different, for example:
In `df_source`: "Stephen Edwin King it"

But at the same time in `df_sort`: "S. King it"

Even though they are different, they are the same book, so I use `fuzzywuzzy`

I wrote code that works. But due to the large volume of files, gradually the code is running slower and slower. Checking the first 15 lines of the `df_sort` took 2 hours.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to make the code faster, maybe I chose the wrong path initially.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from tqdm import tqdm

df_sort     = pd.read_excel('data/sort.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1',   names=["author", "name"],         dtype="string")
df_source   = pd.read_excel('data/list.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1', names=["link", "name", "author"], dtype="string")

result    = pd.DataFrame(columns=["author", "name"])
duplicate = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ratio", "author source", "name source", "author sort", "name sort"])


for row in tqdm(range(11, 13)):
    source_author = df_source['author'].iloc[row]
    source_name   = df_source['name'].iloc[row]
    for row_sort in range(0, len(df_sort)):
        sort_author = df_sort['author'].iloc[row_sort]
        sort_name   = df_sort['name'].iloc[row_sort]
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(f"{source_author} {source_name}", f"{sort_author} {sort_name}")
        if ratio > 70:
            duplicate.loc[len(duplicate.index)] = [ratio, source_author, source_name, sort_author, sort_name]
        else:
            result.loc[len(result.index)] = [sort_author, sort_name]


duplicate.to_csv('out/duplicate.csv', index=False)
result.to_csv('out/result.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Probably won't solve it all the way, but anytime I use nested `for` loops I figure there is a faster way:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283650/python-something-faster-than-2-nested-for-loops

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare each element in two relative large sequence which results in a total of more than `2e+09` string comparision. This is always going to take a while. However there are a couple of things you can do to improve the performance over your current implementation

### use rapidfuzz for string matching

`fuzzywuzzy` has a very slow implementation of these string comparision algorithms. You should be able to improve the performance significantly by simply replacing your usage of `fuzzywuzzy` with [`rapidfuzz`](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) (disclaimer: I am the author)

### calculate similarity matrixes

rapidfuzz provides a way to calculate the similarity for each element in two sequences. This is a lot faster, since it can:

- cache parts of the calculation
- save the overhead of calling into Python
- use multithreading

You can find the full documentation for cdist [here](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html#cdist).

### reduce memory usage

Your code is currently storing all results:

```py
if ratio > 70:
    duplicate.loc[len(duplicate.index)] = [ratio, source_author, source_name, sort_author, sort_name]
else:
    result.loc[len(result.index)] = [sort_author, sort_name]
```

which means you are going to store more than `2e+09` elements. You are going to run out of memory with this at some point. You should probably compare the data in chunks and store the results in between

### consider handling similarity for author / book title independently

you calculate the similarity for author + book title in one step:

```py
fuzz.ratio(f"{source_author} {source_name}", f"{sort_author} {sort_name}")
```

you might want to split this into two comparisons:

```py
fuzz.ratio(source_author, sort_author)
fuzz.ratio(source_name, sort_name)
```

since at least from my understanding this data does not really belong together.

### Example

Here is an example how this could be used in your case. Note that the example only calculates `fuzz.ratio(source_author, sort_author)` for simplicity

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, process

process.cdist(df_source['author'], df_sort['author'], scorer=fuzz.ratio, workers=-1)
```

Note that you are going to have to call this with smaller chunks of your data to avoid it from running out of memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I'll post when I fix the code.